# Netbeans 7.1 / Tomcat Issue

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have two machines:

- Windows 7 - Running Netbeans 7.1
- Windows Server 2003 - Running Tomcat 7.0.27

If I start tomcat from the bin/startup on the 2003 server, everything works fine. I.e., I can hit the tomcat admin console in a browser on either machine, I can deploy webservices, hit those deployed web services from a client on my Windows 7 machine, etc.

But if I try to integrate this tomcat into netbeans things go bad.

1. I added the tomcat instance to my netbeans configuration, using the *add server* wizard.
2. Right click the Apache Tomcat I just created in NB in the services/servers, choose *Start*.
3. The server appears to start and from the content of the tomcat logs everything
   seems fine, at the bottom of the log you see the standard `INFO: Server startup in 41785 ms`.

The tomcat instance isn't running, I cannot hit the tomcat admin URL from either box.

I can see in the Task Manager on the 2003 box that no java.exe is started when I try to start the tomcat instance from netbeans.

Any idea where I should be looking?  I would imagine it has to be a netbeans issue since everything works if I start from the tomcat startup script.

Googled and nothing jumped out at me as something I missed.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans you can register an external server, i.e. a server different from the bundled one. But this server must be on the same machine as Netbeans, AFAIK you can't use a "remote" server in NB.

Comment: Is that really, verifiable so? Because it would make development with NB largely pointless if you're working in a team. I find it hard to believe NB would be so disadvantaged when it comes to Java Servlets (as opposed to PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Youre misunderstanding the main concepts of "developing Web Application (Asp,Java)", and considering them from "Developing Web Script (PHP)" perspective.

PHP is not an app by design, it's a script. So it natively supports using one server for as many developers as you wish.

But in Web application's world - you don't do "coding" on collaborated servers, or machines even. You do the codes by yourself, on your env, and then deploy them to production (or QA and then to production, depends...).
So sory but it is not designed to be used by the way you're trying to use it...